# I am trying to have my "Details" page to reference two seperate parts of my server that are linked via techID

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Okay, so I have my page "List Customers" which then links to "List Jobs" adding on `?custID=` into the URL, then on List jobs I have used `$_GET["custID"]` so my query uses the `custID` from the URL. that works fine, lists out my jobs for said customer using their ID.

My problem comes up now, I need the links on this page to give my third page the `techID` as well. But the `techID` is in `jobDetails`, so my query cannot give them the `techID` as it is querying my `job` section.

This is my "ListJobs.php" page, which upon choosing a customer in the page before it, loads this page with the url `ListJobs.php?custID=001` (001 being an example, it will give the number depending on your choice of customer).

```
<?php 
// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
mysql_select_db($database_con_sim5, $con_sim5);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE custID=" . $_GET["custID"] ;
$Rs1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Rs1)) {
  $strName1 = $row['jobID'] . " " . $row['jobDesc'] . " " . $row['computerName'];
  $strLink = "<a href = 'jobDetails.php?jobID=".$row['jobID']."'>".$strName1."</a>";
  // Write the data of the person
  echo "<li>" . $strLink . " </li>";
}
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Then on pressing one of the links, link to `jobDetails.php?jobID=` with the job number.
I am able to show all the details in Job Detail with this, but I also need my `Tech Name` to appear, `Tech Name` is not in `Job Details`, but `Tech ID` is.
Here is my Job Details page coding :

```
<?php 
// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
mysql_select_db($database_con_sim5, $con_sim5);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM jobDetail WHERE jobID=" . $_GET["jobID"] ;
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT technician.techName FROM technician 
  WHERE techID=" . $query_Recordset1["techID"] ;
$Rs1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
$Rs2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($Rs1)) {
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Rs2)) {
    echo "<dt><strong>Job Note ID:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["jobNoteID"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Job Notes:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["jobNotes"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Date Completed:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["dateCompleted"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Time Spent:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["timeSpent"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Job ID:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["jobID"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Technician ID:</strong></dt><dd>".$row1["techID"]."</dd>";
    echo "<dt><strong>Technician Name:</strong></dt><dd>".$row2["techName"]."</dd>";
  }
}
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

The error I am getting is:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Sim5Server\Pages\jobDetails.php on line 129

That line is:

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Rs2)) {
```

I hope I am making any sense AT ALL.

To sum up, I need my final page to show data from mysql technician using the Primary/index key techID. 
Some way to add techID onto either listJobs' links to job details or in job details' second Recordset.

EDIT:
I should probably state this will never be used on the net, I only need it to work for an assignment. in future, thanks to a comment, I will no longer be using mysql_* I am jsut using them as my entire workbook tells us to use it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you for the information on mysql_* functions. I will definitely keep this information on hand later down the track. I will, however, still be using mysql_* in this as it is only an assignment at TAFE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this change in your `jobDetails.php` page

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM jobDetail WHERE jobID=". (int) $_GET["jobID"];
$Rs1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($Rs1)) {
  $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT technician.techName FROM technician 
  WHERE techID=" . $row1["techID"] ;
  $Rs2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Rs2)) {
```

For the second query you were using the result resource from executing the first query as `techID`. Also you will have to query for `techName` from inside the `while` loop fetching job details, since only then will you have the `techID`.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Your fix works and the explanation tells me exactly what I have done wrong..

Comment: What exactly is the load on the database of running the inner query once for each outer row? I always do this kind of thing as either a single query with a join, or just two queries that are logically "merge joined" in my application code.