# Display image from sql server with php

Tags: php, image, sql-server-2008

I am a beginner here. I have a column type varbinary(max) with images in it and after echoing it, i get a bunch of these random figure on my site:

���*��d���=��O�

Anyone know what this means?

I'm echoing it like this from my database:

```
include 'DB_Connection';
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo $row['image'];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need my PHP page to show my BLOB image from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database)

Comment: Very similar, but this one involves SQL Server instead of MySQL

Comment: is there a good reason to store images in the db? rather than the file system

Comment: @MaxiWheat The storage engine doesn't matter in this case - the issue is with displaying it to the browser (i.e. from PHP).

Comment: @Dagon Since this is my first time, i didn't know anything else and its only 10 images.

Comment: it is generally considered best to not store files in the db. Store their name\path in the db, and then put the files in the files system.

Comment: The number of images is irrelevant, the filesystem is designed to store files, which is how an image should be stored. You should consider switching.

Comment: @Dagon hm, I'm thinking on doing that then.. Will there be many changes if i switch method ?

Comment: many? you know your site\code i don't.

Answer (score 0):

it's jpeg, not jpg.

However, you should store the images in the filesystem.

Also, there's absolutely no reason to have that code within a while loop. It won't do any good after the first time, you can only display one image that way.