# issue with blob image from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

i have store an image into my database.

but i am unable to display the image what i have done till now is under.... any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance!

```
 <?    
         $query="SELECT * from testimonial";
            $ret = mysqli_query($mysql,$query);
            if (isset($ret) && $ret->num_rows>0)
                { 

                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
                        {
                            $body=$row['body'];
                            $name=$row['name'];
                            $image=$row['img'];
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <div class="frame-icon"><? echo "<img src=test_img.php?id=".$row['id']." width=150 height=150/>";?></div>
                                <p class="quote"><?php echo $body; ?><span><?php echo $name; ?></span></p>
                            </li>
                        <?php }
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

and my test_img code is

```
 <?    
        <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])){

$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT *FROM testimonial WHERE id='$id' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $image=$row["img"];
}
 header("content-type: image/png");?>
```

hi Abhik i have try this one but i get something like this

and in my case i have png image so just change the jpeg to png the code you have given

but i got this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgpcMFwwXDANSUhEUlwwXDBcMGRcMFwwXDBkCAZcMFwwXDBw4pVUXDBcMFwwCXBIWXNcMFwwCxNcMFwwCxMBXDCanBhcMFwwCk9pQ0NQUGhvdG9zaG9wIElDQyBwcm9maWxlXDBcMHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHBcMBAIs2Qhc/0jAVww+H48PCtcIsAHvlwwAXjTCwhcMMBNm8AwHIf/D+pCmVxcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUXDBAeo5CplwwQEYBgJ2YJlNcMKAEXDBgy2Ni41wwUC1cMGBcJ3/m01wwgJ34mXsBXDBblCEVAaCRXDAgE2WIRFwwaDtcMKzPVopFXDBY...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">`

Comment: While you add an image make sure you do mysql_real_escape_string() to the data that you are saving.. and better to have the DB column type as LONGBLOB().

Comment: Also can you post your row data for $row['img'] that you get from database to http://codepad.org/, and share the URL, it will be easier to find the issue.

Comment: here is the url                                    http://livephonetracker.com/                                           yes i can show that garbage data with echo $row['img']

Comment: cant open that link please post the $row['img'] that you are getting from DB to the codepad.org

Comment: user name admin and pswd demo

Comment: <? echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['img']) . '">';?>

Comment: I did not get, that site does not tell me anything

Comment: oh i have echo the image like the above code and i get the above garbage value as i have paste it in my qn

Comment: Yes I saw that the issue could be something else may the data is not saved properly in DB

Comment: image is save like this [BLOB - 6.5   KiB] i think its okay

Answer (score 0):

How about if you store the location of the image in DB then store the image itself in the file system? It's a better choice I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to display the blob images stored in DB is

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['img']) . '">';
```