# Php and Mysql Blob image

Tags: php, mysql, blob, jpeg

what I need to do in my website is to show a list of jpg images stored in a Mysql database using Blob type (I don't want to use any other way). but instead of the image I got strings like this

```
����$ExifMM*bj(1r2��i��SI'SI'Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)2014:07:31 20:02:56�����&(."�HH����XICC_PROFILEHLinomntrRGB XYZ � 1acspMSFTIEC sRGB���-HP cprtP3desc�lwtpt�bkptrXYZgXYZ,bXYZ@dmndTpdmdd��vuedL�view�$lumi�meas$tech0rTRC<�gTRC<�bTRC<�textCopyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard CompanydescsRGB IEC61966-2.1sRGB IEC61966-2.1XYZ �Q�XYZ XYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ $����descIEC http://www.iec.chIEC http://www.iec.chdesc.IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB.IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGBdesc,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1,Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1view��_.���\�XYZ L.....
```

This is the code...

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("erossenses@localhost","erossenses","-----","my_erossenses");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Racconti");

echo "<br>";

echo "<font style=\"font-family:Verdana; font-size:15px; color:maroon\"><b><u>Titolo</u></b></font>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";



header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   echo $row['Immagine'];

   echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to echo a PSD file?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525862/747609

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying an image stored in a mysql blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525830/displaying-an-image-stored-in-a-mysql-blob)

Comment: You cannot combine ImageData and normal HTML on one Page. Output your Image with an separated script and use it like this <img src="myimage.php?id=1">

Comment: Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21879970/

Comment: Do not echo the "<br>", also only echo one jpeg image instead of multiple

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate multiple images with php at once.  you can only do them one at a time, so you'd have to do it via ajax. this isn't advisable at all anyway. you're best to learn about ajax and file uploads and how to secure them than wasting any more time on this. Storing images in mysql is suicide, especially for a beginner. You are on the wrong path and learning dangerous habits already.

to advance your skills, read the manual http://php.net/ or better yet, get a quality php book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're echoing a lot of stuff that's not an image. If you set `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` the browser will expect to get only the image data (for just one image).

If you really must use images from the database, a solution would be to create an additional file, let's say `image.php?id=1` which gets the id of the image and displays only that specific image. You can use this file in the src of an img tag.

Comment: Fetching images from the db is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

header("Content-length: $fileSize"); header("Content-type: $fileType"); header("Content-disposition: download; filename=$fileName"); echo $fileData;

Hope file size,name, type, and data stored in table.