# not able to fetch image from blob in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

Code for uploading in the blob :

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("dtbase");
$file = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
echo $file;
$imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']));
$sql="insert into tab1(coname,date,volume,num,eissn,jname,info1,info2,section,logo)values('$coname','$date','$volume','$num','$eissn','$jname','$info1','$info2','$section','{$imgData}')";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
```

Code for retrieving:

```
    $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FRom tab1 WHERE coname='$coname'");
    $im = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
    $img = $im['logo'];
```

Using `$img` to show the image:

```
<img src="$img" />
```

The image does not appear on the web page.

Comment: Try ussing base64 encode

Comment: Images aren't typically inline (in the HTML). Images in the HTML should be links. When the client requests an image from your web server (by full URL like `http://example.com/images/logo.jpg`), then you serve it up in the raw, with the proper mime type header. This keeps the HTML page small and snappy, and images can be downloaded in the web browser in parallel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need my PHP page to show my BLOB image from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($im['logo']).'" alt="photo"><br>';
```

Comment: This method is only recommended for very small images for the reasons explained in my comments above.