# Displaying an image from the DB using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys am having trouble displaying an image from the DB on a web page.

Am using this to display

```
echo "<img
```

src=image.php?"' width=300 height=270/>";

here is my image.PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
$con1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","roots");
mysql_select_db("blog",$con1);
if(!$con1)
{
  die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
}

$q="select image from data where Number=1";
$result= mysql_query($q,$con1);
if($result)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];

}
else
{
  echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is *almost* a good question. If you were to add more description of what happens when you try to run this code, you would improve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need my PHP page to show my BLOB image from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database)

Comment: The code is supposed to get an image stored in the database and display it on index.php

Comment: image tag is not `<image>` it's `<img>`

Answer (score -1):

`echo $row['image'];` simply display the data's fetched from `DB`.

Supposed your `image` column holds data like this `http://domain/project/images/img.jpg`

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" width=300 height=270 />' ;
```