# How can I display image of blob type in php?

Tags: php, mysql, data-uri-scheme

I'm trying to display an image, but that image type is `blob`.

#### Question:

How can I display `blob` data type image?

I tried with:

```
function getBlob() {
     $data = $this->user_model->getBlob();
     echo "<img src="base64_encode( $data['IMAGE'] )">";
}
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need my PHP page to show my BLOB image from mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database)

Comment: i'm using that post ,but its not working ,that's why i'm asking.

Comment: Code in your question doesn't look like one in accepted answer in my link, probably this is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the [`data:URI` scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (*`data:image/jpeg;base64,`*) :

> **Wikipedia:**
>
> *The data URI scheme is a URI scheme (Uniform Resource Identifier scheme) that provides a way to include data in-line in web pages as if they were external resources [...]*

Do it as follow:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $data['IMAGE'] ).'"/>'
```