# Codeiginter header('Content-Type: image/jpg') not displaying text

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, text, blob

I am working with `codeigniter`. I added an `image` as `blob` in `database` and fetch it by using the below code

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');  
 $table="sample_table";
 $select="photo";
     $row=$this->common_mdl->fetch_array($table,$select,"","");

     for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
    { 

     $st= pack("H*",$row[$i]['PHOTO']); 

    // $this->load->view('account/test1',$st);


     }

echo $st;
```

The code works well. But when I try to echo some text on the same page, it didn't show anything, even the image didn't display.

**Is there any way to display text with the same header, or is there any alternate method to do the same without header()**

Any help colud be appreciated

Thank u in advance..

Comment: This answer should be applicable to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13225760/1023562.

Comment: @IvanJovovic, Thank u for the answer.. It works pretty well... :)