# Displaying a date specific image from a databse

Tags: php, mysqli

The aim is for a customer to upload their advert to the database, that triggers and email for approval. Once approved ad will display in location between the set dates.

I have written the code correctly to display by date and approval from an admin area. I just cannot get the image to display.

The code below details the process so far.

```
    <?php 
include('mysql_connect.php');{

  $location='1'; 
  }

 $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE adloc = '$location' AND approval ='Y' ");

if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $id = $rows ['id'];
        $start = $rows ['start'];
        $end = $rows ['enddate'];
        $business = $rows ['business'];
        $email = $rows ['email'];
        $tel = $rows ['tel'];
        $web = $rows ['web'];
        $advert = $rows ['image'];

    $Date = date('Y-m-d');
    $Date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date));; 
    $DateBegin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start"));
    $DateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$end"));
}

if (($Date > $DateBegin) && ($Date < $DateEnd))
    {
      echo "ADVERT";
      echo '<img src="getad.php?id=$id">';

    }
    else
    {
      echo "FILLER IMAGE";  
    }

}
?>
```

The code for the getad.php file is as follows

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id= '$id'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $image = $row['image'];
}
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

I am sure I can't be far off. The image is a JPEG LONGBLOB in the database.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just upload image to a directory and insert file path to database?

Comment: Why is the date not part of the sql query? Make it simple. MySQL has date/time functions.

Comment: I have considered doing that and that is my usual preferred choice hence the rustiness using this method. I preferred this option for organisational reasons. We will be working with a lot of data and would be nice to keep everything in one location .

Comment: You probably need `base64_encode($row['image'])` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database

Comment: this is failing you `mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])` and `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id= '$id'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is failing you:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id= '$id'");
```

Both of those functions require a database connection be passed and as the first parameter:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['id']);
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id= '$id'");
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

However, may need to use `base64_decode`:

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo base64_decode($image);
```

or

```
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $image . '" />';
```

---

Here is an example borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20564797/

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

---

For debugging purposes:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- As well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- 

`code`if (($Date > $DateBegin) && ($Date < $DateEnd))
    {
      echo "ADVERT";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
   
    }
    else
    {
      echo "FILLER IMAGE";  
    }`code`

I have changed to this as above. It still echo the ADVERT however doesnt even display a broken image like it did before.

Comment: @JamesParsons you're welcome. Can you add error reporting and error checking to see if anything comes of it? I made an edit to my answer with that, and unsure if you did see it.

Comment: Sorry quite new here havent quite grasped how to post everything!

Comment: @JamesParsons you may also have to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead of  `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` but I can't be 100% sure about that.

Comment: Notice: Constant DB_USERNAME already defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/mysql_connect.php on line 3

Notice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/mysql_connect.php on line 4

Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/mysql_connect.php on line 5

Notice: Constant DB_DATABASE already defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/mysql_connect.php on line 6

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/date1.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: tel in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/date1.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: web in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/date1.php on line 24
ADVERT
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/date1.php on line 40

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Spire/date1.php on line 40

Comment: @JamesParsons something else is failing you then. Maybe you're doing the same include/require somewhere. and the additional notices doesn't correspond with what you posted.

Comment: Sorry @Fred -ii- here is the error reporting just for date1.php


Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spire/date1.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: tel in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spire/date1.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: web in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spire/date1.php on line 24
ADVERT
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spire/date1.php on line 40

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spire/date1.php on line 40