# use JSON and Display data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a popup which is displayed on clicking a name in this leaderboard :https://jsfiddle.net/pvwvdgLn/1/

There are various fields in the popup like :Name,Email,Date of birth etc which I want to display for the respective person whose name is clicked by the user.

I have below json which is fetching me the array which contains all these data of all the people in the list :

```html
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xxxxx";
$connectioninfo = array(
    'Database' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectioninfo);
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'connection failure';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

$q1 = "select top 10 *
from pointsBadgeTable
WHERE WeekNumber ='week51'
order by pointsRewarded desc";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1);
if ($stmt == false) {
    echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

//Set content type to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Echo a json object to the browser
echo json_encode($result);
?>

As can be seen in the query,it fetches JSON for all the top10 ,whose names can be seen in the list.
```

the html and JS related to the popup is here : https://jsfiddle.net/woef5mn6/

**How can I display the respective data in the popup from the JSON only for the person whose name is clicked ?**

please help me.

Comment: Its more relevant to post the output of this script then to post the script, also when do you load this script and where does the output go?

Comment: @Xorifelse thanks for the input.I will post the JSON data.

Comment: [{"ReportingManager":"Bob Percival","EmployeeName":"Brandon Barnes","WeekNumber":"week51","WeeklyHoursLogged":47,"EmployeeID":2164,"pointsRewarded":120,"Comment":"Employee submitted above 40 hours for the week - per hour extra 10 points","rank":13,"Gold":1,"silver":0,"bronze":0,"LevelField":2.55319,"intoTheGame":1,"Completionist":1,"beyondTheCallOfDuty":0,"Slacker":0,"goGetter":0,"energetic":0,"MngrEmpId":null,"RisingStar":null,"Armageddon":null}]

Comment: this is just for one employee.I am able to pull the data from the url.Now the issue is how do I pull the data such that when one person's name is clicked in the list,only that person's data is displayed in the popup.

Comment: Also, the list that you see in the leaderboard is static.In practice,the list is going to be dynamic.So I am going to echo the list as below -

Comment: <mark>
      <?php  while( $toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) {


        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" ."<script>var id=name;</script>". $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";

      } ?>
       </mark>

Comment: What I am trying to do here is that I have assigned an id to EmployeeName (as you can see in the above php) and I am thinking to use it as key to match the data from the JSON as "EmployeeName " is present in the list of leaderboard too.

Comment: @Xorifelse so now the problem is how to search for the name and match it to whose name is clicked from the list and display the relevant info in the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider using AJAX to fetch additional data. When you print out the list of names do the following:

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT top 10 Employ‌​eeID, EmployeeName, pointsRe‌​warded
          FROM pointsBadgeTable
          WHERE WeekNumber ='week51'
          ORDER BY pointsRewarded desc";

  if(($stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1)) != false){
    do {
      while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
      }
    } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));

    foreach($result as $row){
      echo '<li><mark data-id="'.$row['EmployeeID'].'">'. $row['EmployeeName']. '></mark><small>'.$row['pointsRe‌​warded'].'</small></li>';
    }
  } else {
    // sql error.
  }

?>
```

Then in your JS:

```
$('.leaderboard li').on('click', function () {
  var e = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "./requestuserdata.php", // your script above a little adjusted
    type: "POST",
    data: {id:e.find('mark').data('id')},
    success: function(data){
      $('#popup').fadeIn();
      $('#popup-name').text('Name: ' + data.EmployeeName);
      // etc ..
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('failed, possible script does not exist');
    }
  });
});
```

Then in your PHP file `requestuserdata.php` must contain the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])){
  $q1 = "select *
         from pointsBadgeTable
         WHERE WeekNumber ='week51' AND Employ‌​eeID = '".$_POST['id']."'
         order by pointsRewarded desc";
  // and convert it to JSON like your script above so your javascript does the rest.
  die(json_encode($result));
} else {
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input.Now the point is I am going to echo the list in the leaderboard  from my DB.It is not going to be same as in the fiddle.

Comment: it is going to be like this - <mark> <?php while( $toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) { echo "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" ."<script>var id=name;</script>". $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>"; } ?> </mark>

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying, printing out the list and retrieving additional data are 2 separate scripts.

Comment: how do I set the data-id here ?

Comment: let me try it.I got ur opinion.

Comment: Updated the code a little for generating the list. Now all you need to have, somewhere in your code is the popup container defined in your fiddle as `<div class="popup" id="popup">`. All elements can be empty as Javascript fills it in.

Comment: its giving an error here - foreach($resultt as $row1221){

Comment: this is the error I am getting : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting while (T_WHILE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web1\profile\index.php

Comment: **1.** `requestuserdata.php` should contain only the code I posted, including your way on how to connect to the db above it, nothing more. **2.** when you print your list, the code prints the `<li><mark></mark></li>` code. So place it within `<div class="leaderboard">`my code`</div>`, nothing more, no html, nothing. **3.** the response looks like it doesnt execute PHP, not sure whats going on there. Is the file named `requestuserdata.php` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133493/discussion-between-jane-and-xorifelse).