# Problem displaying images saved as blob images

Tags: php, html, mysqli

am having an issue displaying images stored as blob in my database, as the images doesn't display rather is shows crazy characters and symbols, i tried to change the tags for the php but with no avail. Help and here is my code: Note that i want all types of images to be saved as blob (jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, png) - thanks in advance

```
    <?php
        include 'include/connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM room_details ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2, 1;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    ?>


        <div class="room-thumb"><?php echo '<img alt="room 3" class="img-responsive" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'">'; ?>
            <div class="mask">
              <div class="main">
                <h5><?= $row['room_type']; ?></h5>
                <div class="price"><?= $row['room_name']; ?><span>a night</span></div>
              </div>

                <a href="room-detail.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Read More</a>
              </div>
          </div>

          } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post the rendered link from the src attribute with all the characters and symbols.

Comment: room 3��@�B8�DX�Fx�H��J��L؄N��P�R8�TX�Vx�X��Z��\؅^��`�b8�dX�fx�h��j��l؆n��p�r8�tX�vx�x��z��|؇~�����8��X��x��������؈������8��X��x��������؉���E���8��X��x��������؊������8��X��x��������؋������8

Comment: that's how it displays i really don't like blob but am pushed to use them (i never used before)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP display image BLOB from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the blob url is decoded with base64, you need to encode it first. You can use either **JavaScript** or **PHP** to do this.

### JavaScript:

With JavaScript, you can just use the [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) function to encode your base64 url like this:

```html
<script>
  var x = <?php echo $row['image'] ?>
  document.getELementById("code").innerHTML = atob(x);
</script>

<div class="room-thumb"><?php echo '<img alt="room 3" class="img-responsive" src="data:image;base64,' ?><span id="code"></span><?php echo '">'; ?>
    <!-- DIV CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

However, as stated in this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript), it would be a better approach if you use PHP itself or other JavaScript approaches (mentioned in that same thread) to retrieve and encode the base64 url as the above approach is not secure.

---

### PHP:

With PHP, you can either encode the base64 url before outputting it into your HTML like this:

```
<?php echo '<img alt="room 3" class="img-responsive" src="data:image;base64,' . base64_encode(.$row['image']).'">'; ?>
```

---

Or you can create a new php file, encode the PHP in that file and then echo the encoded base64 url to your HTML like this:

```html
    <!-- PHP file -->
    <?php
      $id = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
      $image = base64_encode(getImageFromDatabase($id)); // your code to fetch the image
    
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      echo $image;
    ?>

    <!-- HTML -->
    <img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $image_id; ?>" />
```

---

Check out the accepted answer in this other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225726/i-need-my-php-page-to-show-my-blob-image-from-mysql-database/#13225760) for a more in-depth explanation of the above two PHP approaches.

Comment: thank you all for your time, its working very fine - AndrewL64 i really appreciate